# How to manage multiple role in React JS APP?

Tags: reactjs, authorization, roles

If I store the logged in user role in localstorage (i.e. user). So user will only see the user's dashboard. But if logged in user manully change the role in localstorage to admin. Then user now can see the content of admin dashboard. I just want to know how to fix this.

Comment: Your solution would mean that someone could open dev tools and set the role to admin, and then access functionality that he is not authorized for.

Comment: don't store the role or other user details in local storage. only store the token information in localstorage and fetch the other data from the server on refresh and keep the user data inside the state (redux or component state). as a best practice check the user role in your backend before responding with information

Comment: @hellogoodnight Correct.

Comment: @sojin So you want to say that, I have to fetch the user details every time any component load.

Comment: @SNSharma No, you have to build functionality in your backend that checks authorization on every request. The problem really isn't that an unauthorized user can access admin components, but rather that he can view and/or edit data there, which is only possible through API calls.

Comment: No only load the details first time(only once when user reload the page manually). and store this information in a common reducer/store or in your root component. you ca use either context API or react-redux to create common store

Comment: Suppose I have sidebar for different roles. Then how i show and hide the sidebar elements based on role type?

Answer (score 2):

I hope these steps can help you

- you can store the user role in the app (ContextApi or Redux).
- and keep the token in the local storage.
- when you reload the app you can use the `useEffect` hook to send a request to the backend to know what is the user's role.
- and then edit the stored data.
- and when you add any component to your app you can access what the user type can see this component and render it just for the suitable users.

you can take a look in [this article](https://isamatov.com/react-permissions-and-roles/)